# how to find out the state of registers and the stack of an .exe with python script

Tags: python, stack, reverse-engineering, cpu-registers, fuzzer

I'm writing a fuzzer and I need to change the configuration file and run some .exe file that uses it, and try to break in this way .exe. I would like to know if Python has the ability to view the state of registers and stack of any application, so that I can understand the reason for the application crash. For example .exe reads some int value, and uses it as length for the string, so if I change this value and it causes buffer overflow, a wanna to know the stack and registers statement at that moment.

Comment: It seems to me that what you want to do is the  work of a debugger. Recente version of gdb can scripted with python and can run on wiwdows. Look at https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ for details.

Comment: i found all needed information in book "gray hat python" Justin Seitz